# Google Analytics Not Detecting Tracking Code

Tags: google, google-analytics

I installed google analytics tracking code on my website. It is not being detected on the google analytics app.

I did notice though that the default url in the google analytics app is set to `http://jobrangers.com` and my site redirects to `http://jobrangers.com/en`.

Can someone please assist me in getting the tracking software on Google to pick up the installed tracking code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your page and noticed that Google Tag Assistant is indicating that the tag is installed correctly. I observed that your page is sending a pageview hit back to GA as well. Your GA code looks good on your site - correctly placed. Are you still having problems? You can also check in Real-Time reports if you are tracking hits. If you are, then it looks like everything is good and you have nothing to worry about.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your site yourself or did you use a cms like WordPress? If yes to the cms, you may need to check with the company that developed your cms to see where the code needs to be inserted. Some cms' s even have a special location in their acp where you need to insert the code.
If you built the site yourself, did you place the code snippet in its entirety in your site before the  tag on every page you wish to track?

Comment: http://jobrangers.com its right in the head

Comment: It has to be the last thing before the head closes. You have it at the top.

Comment: i tried that too. do you think that setting the analytics app property default url to jobrangers.com and then the site redirects to jobrangers.com/en has anything to do with it?

Comment: I've never seen that cause an issue...when i check your site on http://www.gachecker.com/ the analytics js inst detected anywhere on any pages. Seems to me like it will be location that it was inserted.

Comment: Now when i check the site i see the UA code on all pages. How long ago did you add that code before checking to see if the GA app could detect it?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like google analytics is tracking the incorrect url. Check your code to make sure it is placed correctly on you site, hosted or otherwise, and then make sure it is directed at the correct URL.